# Iterate through words of a file in Python

Tags: python, file, io

I need to iterate through the words of a large file, which consists of a single, long long line. I am aware of methods iterating through the file line by line, however they are not applicable in my case, because of its single line structure.

Any alternatives?

Comment: read small amounts of the file with a buffer... `my_file.read(200)`

Answer (score 8):

It really depends on your definition of *word*. But try this:

```
f = file("your-filename-here").read()
for word in f.split():
    # do something with word
    print word
```

This will use whitespace characters as word boundaries.

Of course, remember to properly open and close the file, this is just a quick example.

Answer (score 6):

Long long line? I assume the line is too big to reasonably fit in memory, so you want some kind of buffering.

First of all, this is a bad format; if you have any kind of control over the file, make it one word per line.

If not, use something like:

```
line = ''
while True:
    word, space, line = line.partition(' ')
    if space:
        # A word was found
        yield word
    else:
        # A word was not found; read a chunk of data from file
        next_chunk = input_file.read(1000)
        if next_chunk:
            # Add the chunk to our line
            line = word + next_chunk
        else:
            # No more data; yield the last word and return
            yield word.rstrip('\n')
            return
```

Comment: You should keep in mind that this one work okay when you want to write one word per line to a file, but don't work if you just want to use it so that it yields only one word. This one don't work when we have `dog\ncat` in chunk. It yields `dog\ncat`, not `dog`, then `cat`. When `dog\ncat` is printed it looks ok, but this is illusive.

Answer (score 4):

You really should consider using [Generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

```
def word_gen(file):
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            yield word

with open('somefile') as f:
    word_gen(f)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are more efficient ways of doing this, but syntactically, this might be the shortest:

```
 words = open('myfile').read().split()
```

If memory is a concern, you aren't going to want to do this because it will load the entire thing into memory, instead of iterating over it.

Answer (score 1):

I've answered a similar question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37760181/2089675), but I have refined the method used in that answer and here is the updated version (copied from a recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40858361/2089675)):

> Here is my totally functional approach which avoids having to read and
> split lines. It makes use of the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module:
>
> #### Note for python 3, replace `itertools.imap` with `map`
>
> ```
> import itertools
>
> def readwords(mfile):
>     byte_stream = itertools.groupby(
>       itertools.takewhile(lambda c: bool(c),
>           itertools.imap(mfile.read,
>               itertools.repeat(1))), str.isspace)
>
>     return ("".join(group) for pred, group in byte_stream if not pred)
> ```
>
> Sample usage:
>
> ```
> >>> import sys
> >>> for w in readwords(sys.stdin):
> ...     print (w)
> ... 
> I really love this new method of reading words in python
> I
> really
> love
> this
> new
> method
> of
> reading
> words
> in
> python
>            
> It's soo very Functional!
> It's
> soo
> very
> Functional!
> >>>
> ```
>
> I guess in your case, this would be the way to use the function:
>
> ```
> with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
>     for word in readwords(f):
>         print(word)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Read in the line as normal, then split it on whitespace to break it down into words?

Something like:

```
word_list = loaded_string.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the line you could do:

```
l = len(pattern)
i = 0
while True:
    i = str.find(pattern, i)
    if i == -1:
        break
    print str[i:i+l] # or do whatever
    i += l
```

Alex.

Answer (score 0):

What Donald Miner suggested looks good. Simple and short. I used the below in a code that I have written some time ago:

```
l = []
f = open("filename.txt", "rU")
for line in f:
    for word in line.split()
        l.append(word)
```

longer version of what Donald Miner suggested.