# Reading a text file and splitting it into single words in python

Tags: python, string, split

I have this text file made up of numbers and words, for example like this - `09807754 18 n 03 aristocrat 0 blue_blood 0 patrician` and I want to split it so that each word or number will come up as a new line.

A whitespace separator would be ideal as I would like the words with the dashes to stay connected.

This is what I have so far:

```
f = open('words.txt', 'r')
for word in f:
    print(word)
```

not really sure how to go from here, I would like this to be the output:

```
09807754
18
n
3
aristocrat
...
```

Comment: Does that data literally have quotes around it? Is it `"09807754 18 n 03 aristocrat 0 blue_blood 0 patrician"` or `09807754 18 n 03 aristocrat 0 blue_blood 0 patrician` in the file?

Comment: I follow-up with comment above.
Does that data literally have quotes around it

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Given this file:

```
$ cat words.txt
line1 word1 word2
line2 word3 word4
line3 word5 word6
```

If you just want one word at a time (ignoring the meaning of spaces vs line breaks in the file):

```
with open('words.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
           print(word)
```

Prints:

```
line1
word1
word2
line2
...
word6
```

Similarly, if you want to [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/298607) the file into a single flat list of words in the file, you might do something like this:

```
with open('words.txt') as f:
    flat_list=[word for line in f for word in line.split()]

>>> flat_list
['line1', 'word1', 'word2', 'line2', 'word3', 'word4', 'line3', 'word5', 'word6']
```

Which can create the same output as the first example with `print '\n'.join(flat_list)`...

Or, if you want a nested list of the words in each line of the file (for example, to create a matrix of rows and columns from a file):

```
with open('words.txt') as f:
    matrix=[line.split() for line in f]

>>> matrix
[['line1', 'word1', 'word2'], ['line2', 'word3', 'word4'], ['line3', 'word5', 'word6']]
```

If you want a regex solution, which would allow you to filter `wordN` vs `lineN` type words in the example file:

```
import re
with open("words.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in re.findall(r'\bword\d+', line):
            # wordN by wordN with no lineN
```

Or, if you want that to be a line by line generator with a regex:

```
 with open("words.txt") as f:
     (word for line in f for word in re.findall(r'\w+', line))
```

Comment: How a file object is iterable (`for line in f:`)?

Comment: @haccks: It is the [suggested idiom](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) for looping line-by-line over a file. See also [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8010133/298607)

Comment: I just wanted to know the mechanism behind this; how it works?

Comment: The `open` creates a file object. Python file objects support line-by-line iteration for text files (binary files are read in one gulp...)  So each loop in the `for` loop is a line for a text file. At the end of the file, the file object raises `StopIteration` and we are done with the file. More understanding, of the mechanism is beyond what I can do in a comments.

Comment: You can also load into main memory and use "re" library like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633274/extracting-words-from-a-string-removing-punctuation-and-returning-a-list-with-s

Comment: I love the different ways and the discussion of when each might be used. Very clear, concise, and thorough.

Comment: Maybe we should care about closing the file ? @dawg

Comment: @FlorentJousse: When you use `with` to open the file, the file is closed at the end of the `with` block. No need to manually close it. If you use a bare `open` it is indeed good practice to close that file when finished. All the examples here use `with` and therefor there is no close to worry about.

Comment: Okay thanks you dawg, I was using your code into a loop and I was wondering if the close() was missing. Well that's perfect !

Answer (score 22):

```
f = open('words.txt')
for word in f.read().split():
    print(word)
```

Answer (score 16):

As supplementary, 
if you are reading a vvvvery large file, and you don't want read all of the content into memory at once, you might consider using a **buffer**, then return each word by yield:

```
def read_words(inputfile):
    with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
        while True:
            buf = f.read(10240)
            if not buf:
                break

            # make sure we end on a space (word boundary)
            while not str.isspace(buf[-1]):
                ch = f.read(1)
                if not ch:
                    break
                buf += ch

            words = buf.split()
            for word in words:
                yield word
        yield '' #handle the scene that the file is empty

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for word in read_words('./very_large_file.txt'):
        process(word)
```

Comment: For those interested in performance, this is an order of magnitude faster than the itertools answer.

Comment: why 10240 ? Im assuming that bytes? So around 10kb? How big can the buffer be and if I am interested in performance is smaller or larger buf better?

Comment: Im confuesed, what does process do? It isn't defined...

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is use nltk to tokenize words and then store all of the words in a list, here's what I did.
If you don't know nltk; it stands for natural language toolkit and is used to process natural language. Here's some resource if you wanna get started
[http://www.nltk.org/book/]

```
import nltk 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 
file = open("abc.txt",newline='')
result = file.read()
words = word_tokenize(result)
for i in words:
       print(i)
```

The output will be this:

```
09807754
18
n
03
aristocrat
0
blue_blood
0
patrician
```

Answer (score 4):

```
with open(filename) as file:
    words = file.read().split()
```

Its a List of all words in your file.

```
import re
with open(filename) as file:
    words = re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z\-]+)", file.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my totally functional approach which avoids having to read and split lines. It makes use of the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module:

#### Note for python 3, replace `itertools.imap` with `map`

```
import itertools

def readwords(mfile):
    byte_stream = itertools.groupby(
        itertools.takewhile(lambda c: bool(c),
            itertools.imap(mfile.read,
                itertools.repeat(1))), str.isspace)

    return ("".join(group) for pred, group in byte_stream if not pred)
```

Sample usage:

```
>>> import sys
>>> for w in readwords(sys.stdin):
...     print (w)
... 
I really love this new method of reading words in python
I
really
love
this
new
method
of
reading
words
in
python
           
It's soo very Functional!
It's
soo
very
Functional!
>>>
```

I guess in your case, this would be the way to use the function:

```
with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
    for word in readwords(f):
        print(word)
```