# Python - Words in a file: color or colour? (Grok Learning)

Tags: python, file, grok

**This is a problem on Introduction to Programming 2 on Grok Learning that I am having some trouble with this so please be simple in your coding as I'm new.** 
*The problem is as follows:*

Write a program that reads in a word (e.g. colour or color) and checks if it occurs in the file book.txt, printing out  was found in the book. or  was not found in the book..

For example, given the book.txt file:

book.txt **(This is the first file provided to you by grok)**

He looked out from the top of the mountain .
The colour of the sky was amazing .
Reds , oranges and pinks faded into a hazy blue.
then your program should work like this:

Word to look for: colour
colour was found in the book.

book.txt           **(This is the second file provided to you by Grok)**

Hypothesize ? How was she going to form a
hypothesis when she didn't even know what the
rest of the data looked like ?
then your program should work like this:

Word to look for: hypothesize
hypothesize was found in the book.
This is the code that I have for it as of now.

```
open('book.txt')
word = input('Word to look for: ')

if word in open('book.txt').read() or open('book.txt2').read():

  print(word + " was found in the book.")

else:

  print(word + " was not found in the book.")
```

- The code has troubles when the user inputs "color", even though it is not in either files but seems to have no problem with other words.

Comment: `if word in open('book.txt').read() or open('book.txt2').read():` is not doing what you think it is...

Comment: storytime on SO. we dont care we just want to fix code

Comment: Also, is all that text really needed? You need to describe the problem you are having, there's no need to include the entire exercise

Comment: Which way should it be done? (For loop, reading over the code?)

Comment: Already voted to close this question, but here is the dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value

Comment: is it not about reading from .txt files? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922214/reading-a-text-file-and-splitting-it-into-single-words-in-python

Comment: watered the text down a few words, my apologies

Comment: Why all of the downvotes?

Comment: Hint: `if word in open('book.txt').read() or word in open('book.txt2').read():`

Answer (score 0):

```
word = input("Word to look for: ")
w = False

with open('book.txt','r') as file:
  for line in file:
    if word in line.lower():
      print(word + " was found in the book.")
      w = True
      break
if w == False:
  print(word + " was not found in the book.")
```

**Finally got the answer**