# Splitting the text into words in python

Tags: python, text

While preparing the data (text file) for preprocessing.
I am not able to split the text file into words.

```
import io
f = io.open("pg5200.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
text = f.read()
f.close()

import re
words = re.split(r'\W+', text)
print(words[:100])
```

After using the above code:  The problem is I am getting an extra blank space (" ") in the beginning.

May I know why this extra space is occurring and how can I remove it??

Thank You

Comment: Use this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922214/reading-a-text-file-and-splitting-it-into-single-words-in-python/16922328 It may help you.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show a small example of `pg5200.txt` that recreates your problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `re.findall` ? It seems to be more appropriate for your case: you could try `re.findall(r'\w+', text)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strip` function.

Check this answer
[How do I trim whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185524/how-do-i-trim-whitespace)