# What is the simplist way to take the first 1000 or defined number of words from .txt file with Python?

Tags: python, text

Here is the context for the question: I have a .txt file that contains verses of scripture line by line. Each line contains a distinct number of words. Anyway, is there a way to take the first 1000 words the file, create a distinct file (like for instance  Block 1) and input the information into that file, and then creating another one with the next 1000 words from which the first 1000 words were taken and so on and so forth, while also ignoring the numbers of chapters?
A response would be greatly appreciated since I am doing this for a person statistical project.

Comment: you can read the text and split it into words https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922214/reading-a-text-file-and-splitting-it-into-single-words-in-python and then just selecting the first x number of words. As a new user, make sure to look around first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
from string import ascii_letters

with open( 'scripture.txt' ) as fin :
    text = fin.read()

valid_characters = ascii_letters + '\n\t '
text = ''.join( t for t in text if t in valid_characters )
text = text.split()

for i in range(len(text)//1000) :
    with open( 'part_%03d.txt' % i, 'w') as fout :
        thousand_words = text[i*1000:min((i+1)*1000,len(text))]
        fout.write( ' '.join( thousand_words ))
```

Comment: This code return this error: ```for i in range(len(text) / 1000) :
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer```

Comment: @S.R.Colledge please, use `//` or wrap in `int( ... )`

Comment: Ya I was thinking all I had to do was put ```for i in range(len(text) // 1000)``` so that it would do integer division

Comment: Is there a way for it to skip past the numbers? Because it is putting in the 1:1, 1:2 which I don't want in the file

Comment: @S.R.Colledge please refer to the updated answer (`ascii_letters` etc.)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('scripture_verses.txt') as f:
    words = []
    i = 0
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            words.append(word)
            i += 1
            if i % 1000 == 0:
                with open('out{}.txt'.format(i // 1000), 'w') as out:
                    print(' '.join(words), file=out)
                words = []
    else:
        with open('out{}.txt'.format(i // 1000 + 1), 'w') as out:
            print(' '.join(words), file=out)
        words = []
```

Comment: This one suffers the same problem as the other one. It is including the numbers in it too. Is there a way for it to ignore numbers? Such that "1:1" or "1:21" are ignored?