# Reading a very large file word by word in Python

Tags: python, io, large-files, yield

I have some pretty large text files (>2g) that I would like to process word by word.  The files are space-delimited text files with no line breaks (all words are in a single line).  I want to take each word, test if it is a dictionary word (using enchant), and if so, write it to a new file.

This is my code right now:

```
with open('big_file_of_words', 'r') as in_file:
        with open('output_file', 'w') as out_file:
            words = in_file.read().split(' ')
            for word in word:
                if d.check(word) == True:
                    out_file.write("%s " % word)
```

I looked at [lazy method for reading big file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python), which suggests using `yield` to read in chunks, but I am concerned that using chunks of predetermined size will split words in the middle.  Basically, I want chunks to be as close to the specified size while splitting only on spaces.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Combine the last word of one chunk with the first of the next:

```
def read_words(filename):
    last = ""
    with open(filename) as inp:
        while True:
            buf = inp.read(10240)
            if not buf:
                break
            words = (last+buf).split()
            last = words.pop()
            for word in words:
                yield word
        yield last

with open('output.txt') as output:
    for word in read_words('input.txt'):
        if check(word):
            output.write("%s " % word)
```

Comment: what is the **'last'** used for ? can we **go without it**?

Comment: This has a bug in it if a space is at the end of `buf` after a read and then a split word at the end of the buf on the following read.

If testfile.txt: `This is a file with some text in it and no newlines. Some text has punctuation. Test this file out with multiple buffer sizes.`

and the read size is 20: `inp.read(20)`

You'll see `withsome` `andno` and  `punctuation.Test` concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get away with something similar to an answer on the question you've linked to, but combining `re` and `mmap`, eg:

```
import mmap
import re

with open('big_file_of_words', 'r') as in_file, with open('output_file', 'w') as out_file:
    mf = mmap.mmap(in_file.fileno(), 0, access=ACCESS_READ)
    for word in re.finditer('\w+', mf):
        # do something
```

Comment: For OSX user you need to change with that `access=mmap.ACCESS_READ`

Answer (score 0):

fortunately Petr Viktorin has already written code for us.  The following code reads a chunk from a file, then does a `yield` for each contained word.  If a word spans chunks, that's handled also.

```
line = ''
while True:
    word, space, line = line.partition(' ')
    if space:
        # A word was found
        yield word
    else:
        # A word was not found; read a chunk of data from file
        next_chunk = input_file.read(1000)
        if next_chunk:
            # Add the chunk to our line
            line = word + next_chunk
        else:
            # No more data; yield the last word and return
            yield word.rstrip('\n')
            return
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745406/143880

Comment: not for each word, see my comment under Petr answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745406/143880